# individual padding per page when printing html document: padding-top for only affects on the first page, padding-bottom only on the last page

Tags: html, css, printing, padding

I am writing a book using html and css.

Is there a way to give extra padding-top and padding-bottom for each page when printing? When printing, margin-top and padding-top only affect the first page, and margin-bottom and padding-bottom only affect the last page. The corresponding part of the CSS file is as follows:

```
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

html, body {
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0; 
}


body {
    font-family: 'Noto Serif CJK KR'; font-weight:350; line-height: 1.65em; vertical-align: middle; text-align: justify; word-break: break-word; line-break: auto; zoom: 1; font-size: 1.25em;
    color: black;
    background: #eaeaea;
}


@media print {
    @page {
    size: A4;
    margin-top: 30mm;
    margin-bottom: 27mm;
    }
    @page :left {
    margin-left: 14mm;
    margin-right: 14mm;
    }
    @page :right {
    margin-left: 14mm;
    margin-right: 14mm;
    }
    html, body {
    zoom: 1;
    padding: 0.6em 0; / <- 0.6em works only the first page for padding-top and the last page for padding-bottom.
    }
}
```

I would see more background colour below the last line on each page and above the first line on each page. You can see how narrow the background colour is below the last line on one page and above the first line on the next:
[too narrow background colour above/below text per page](https://github.com/prko/how_to_add_padding-top_-_padding-bottom_on_each_page_for_printing/blob/main/images%20of%20current%20%26%20expected%20results/current.png)

I did all the things I found on the internet and by using an AI-based chatbot for several days.
What I am expecting is the following result:
[expected result](https://github.com/prko/how_to_add_padding-top_-_padding-bottom_on_each_page_for_printing/blob/main/images%20of%20current%20%26%20expected%20results/expected.png?fbclid=IwAR3gLghz4IvuselzoCd4hvHMSlN5nG2Xb-BWqLU1_mJlpxBcsNd05JfLxyg)

I also attach the corresponding HTML file and the corresponding CSS file:
https://github.com/prko/how_to_add_padding-top_-_padding-bottom_on_each_page_for_printing